# How do I render user Login block in main menu?

Tags: 7, theming

I wrote the following code but I see only 'array' word.

```
function mytheme_menu_tree__primary(&$variables) {
   return '<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">' . $variables['tree'] . module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login')['content']  
    . '</ul>'; 

}
```

Comment: Which drupal version are you using?

Comment: Has to be Drupal 7 @SandeepReddy. Drupal 6 didn't have `hook_block_view` and Drupal 8 doesn't have `module_invoke`. There are other hints too

Comment: I'm using drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block content can either be a string or a render array. As such you need to run it through [`render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/render/7.x):

```
$block_content = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login')['content'];
return '<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">' . $variables['tree'] . render($block_content) . '</ul>';
```

It's worth bearing in mind that the user login form isn't wrapped in `<li>` tags, so unless you're altering the markup for that form elsewhere, your code will produce invalid markup.

Comment: where should I write this code? in template.php file of my theme?